# How to create a temporary table using the BigQuery Ruby library?

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I can't find a corresponding option in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/Google-Cloud-Bigquery-Dataset#Google__Cloud__Bigquery__Dataset_create_table_instance_). Is it possible to create a temporary table with the BigQuery Ruby library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your 'temporary' means you want to create a table only for one time usage.

In that case, as far as I know, there is no direct option but you can create and then delete it like a transactional behavior

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new
dataset = bigquery.dataset "my_dataset"

# Do something with the dataset

dataset.delete
```